# Should i have to set proxy for consuming web services in android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, proxy

I am working on a computer that is joined with server in LAN.proxy is used to access internet in my computer, now i am doing project on consuming php web services which give JSON as output.i have made a app for it but it gives blank response,i have read one of the stack overflow question answer that say that it is because of proxy.
should i have to set proxy setting in my application.
And how can i set proxy for this problem.

i have set the proxy by this step

1. Click on Menu
2. Click on Settings
3. Click on Wireless & Networks
4. Go to Mobile Networks
5. Go to Access Point Names
6. Here you will Telkila Internet, click on it.
7. In the Edit access point section, input the "proxy" and "port"
8. Also provide the Username and Password, rest of the fields leave them blank

internet is working in emulator,but still project display nothing.
this is my code

```
package com.example.jsonexaple2;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;

public class Jsonexaple2 extends Activity {
    String archiveQuery = "http://www.archive.org/advancedsearch.php?q=Lotus&fl[]=date&fl[]=format&fl[]=identifier&fl[]=mediatype&fl[]=title&sort[]=createdate+desc&sort[]=&sort[]=&rows=10&page=1&output=json&callback=callback&save=yes";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jsonexaple2);
        InputStream in = null;
        String queryResult = "";
        try {
         URL url = new URL(archiveQuery);
         HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
         HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
         httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
         httpConn.connect();
         in = httpConn.getInputStream();
         BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
         ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
         int read = 0;
         int bufSize = 512;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[bufSize];
         while(true){
          read = bis.read(buffer);
          if(read==-1){
           break;
          }
          baf.append(buffer, 0, read);
         }
         queryResult = new String(baf.toByteArray());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         // DEBUG
         Log.e("DEBUG: ", e.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
         // DEBUG
         Log.e("DEBUG: ", e.toString());
        }
        JSONObject jObject;
        try {
         jObject = new JSONObject(queryResult.replace("callback(", "")).getJSONObject("response");
         JSONArray docsArray = jObject.getJSONArray("docs");
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          if (docsArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("mediatype").equals("etree")) {
           String title = docsArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("title");
           String identifier = docsArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("identifier");
           String date = docsArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("date");
           System.out.println(title + " " + identifier + " " + date);
          }
         }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
         // DEBUG
         Log.e("DEBUG: ", e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to. Once, I had the same problem with the emulator. I searched on Google and I found these two blogs that are nice.

- [gitshah](http://www.gitshah.com/2011/02/android-fixing-no-internet-connection.html?showComment=1344511892100#c5603712472032022102)
- [twozao](http://blog.twozao.com/2010/12/connect-to-internet-in-android-emulator.html)

Hope that it will help you.